# ld cannot find existing 32-bit libm

Tags: compiling, g++

I'm only posting after exhausting all other answers I could find on google. I still can't figure out my problem. I try to use g++ to compile in 32-bit on a Red Hat machine. This is my command:

```
BITS=32
OS=`uname -s`

g++ -D$OS -O3 -Wall -pipe -m$BITS -c *.cpp
```

But the linker can't find a library:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But... 32-bit libm.so exists in the usual place.

```
>file /usr/lib/libm.so 
/usr/lib/libm.so: symbolic link to `../../lib/libm.so.6'
>file /lib/libm.so.6 
/lib/libm.so.6: symbolic link to `libm-2.12.so'
>file /lib/libm-2.12.so 
/lib/libm-2.12.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped
```

I tried the simple stuff, like checked that /usr/lib is still actually listed in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and I tried adding -lm to the g++ command.

These are all the glibc packages installed (glibc provides libm.so and libm.a):

```
compat-glibc.x86_64                  1:2.5-46.2
compat-glibc-headers.x86_64          1:2.5-46.2
glibc.i686                           2.12-1.132.el6
glibc.x86_64                         2.12-1.132.el6
glibc-common.x86_64                  2.12-1.132.el6
glibc-devel.i686                     2.12-1.132.el6
glibc-devel.x86_64                   2.12-1.132.el6
glibc-headers.x86_64                 2.12-1.132.el6
glibc-utils.x86_64                   2.12-1.132.el6
```

I also came across a suggestion to run:

```
>readelf -a /usr/lib/libm.so | grep PATH
```

but it outputs nothing.

Any other thoughts or ideas? Is it possible to get a complaint from the linker when something else is wrong? Any response is much appreciated.

Comment: The `g++` command you listed is compile-only, it shouldn't attempt to link at all. What's the command you used for linking?

Comment: That does not solve your problem, but you should use `OS=$(uname -s)` and `g++ -D"$OS" -O3 -Wall -pipe -m"$BITS" -c *.cpp`

Comment: Oh, I use `g++ --static -L. -D$OS -O3 -Wall -pipe -m$BITS -o foo *.o`

Comment: oh no... it's the static option isn't it... looking into this now.

Comment: You need `libm.a` to link, but you should have it since `glibc-devel.i686` is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm silly. It was indeed the `--static` option in my linking command. In lieu of the static libraries, I got rid of the `--static`, worked through some errors related to the code, and it compiles correctly. Thanks for the responses.